# Changing Legend in ggplot and ggwordcloud

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a word cloud using a tidytuesday data set (how many times Roy Kent says fuck per episode of Ted Lasso). This is my first time using the ggwordcloud package and I'm wondering how I change the words that are used to represent the colors on a mapping.

setup

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggwordcloud)
library(showtext)
library(tidyverse)
```

data

```
tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2023, week = 39)
fuck <- tuesdata$richmondway
```

data for plot

```
fuck_plot <- fuck |>
              select("Season_Episode", "F_count_RK", "Dating_flag", "Coaching_flag") |>
              mutate(word = "FUCK")
```

fonts and such

```
font_add_google("Oswald", "os")
showtext_auto()
plot_font <- "os"
```

plot

```
fp <- fuck_plot |>
        ggplot(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = word, size = F_count_RK, color = Dating_flag)) +
          geom_text_wordcloud_area(
            aes(color = Dating_flag),
            eccentricity = .5,
            seed = 289,
            tstep = 0.04,
            family = "os",
            fontface = "bold",
            show.legend = TRUE
          ) +
          scale_size_area(max_size = 40) +
          scale_color_manual(
            labels = c("Hell No", "Hell Yea"), 
            values = c("black", "#e0218a"), 
            name = "Is Rick Dating Keeley?"
          ) +
          coord_cartesian(
            expand = FALSE
          )  +
          guides(size = "none") +
          theme_void() +
          theme(
            plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
            legend.position = c(0.5, 0.75)
          )
```

As you can see in the legend, the text that shows what the colors are is "NA", is there a way to change this to something more appropriate, like FUCK.

[image: word cloud]

Comment: I am ok with this, but I suspect the downvotes may be related to all the `_uck`s in the example. Maybe choose a milder example?

Comment: Yeah, we almost need a not-safe-for-work tag for this one. The question itself is reasonable, it's just not an image you can keep on the screen in a professional setting. But normally those values in the legend are set by the "glyph" property. Not sure what the default for the wordcloud geom is though.

Comment: Sorry if the non-work related letters on your computer screen offended you while you were at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that an `NA` is displayed in the legend actually looks like a bug to me (FYI: I already filed an [issue](https://github.com/lepennec/ggwordcloud/issues/21) on GH).

Besides of that you could set the label or text to be displayed as the legend key glyph by setting the `label` via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`, e.g. `"a"` or `"A"` or whatever content you want to display including `F***`:

```
p +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(
    aes(color = Dating_flag),
    eccentricity = .5,
    seed = 289,
    tstep = 0.04,
    fontface = "bold",
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "F***")))
```

[image]

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggwordcloud)

p <- fuck_plot |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = 0, y = 0, label = word,
    size = F_count_RK,
    color = Dating_flag
  )) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
  scale_color_manual(
    labels = c("Hell No", "Hell Yea"),
    values = c("black", "#e0218a"),
    name = "Is Rick Dating Keeley?"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(
    expand = FALSE
  ) +
  guides(size = "none", fill = "none") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.position = c(0.5, 0.75)
  )
```

**DATA**

```
fuck_plot <- structure(list(Season_Episode = c(
  "S1_e1", "S1_e2", "S1_e3",
  "S1_e4", "S1_e5", "S1_e6", "S1_e7", "S1_e8", "S1_e9", "S1_e10",
  "S2_e1", "S2_e2", "S2_e3", "S2_e4", "S2_e5", "S2_e6", "S2_e7",
  "S2_e8", "S2_e9", "S2_e10", "S2_e11", "S2_e12", "S3_e1", "S3_e2",
  "S3_e3", "S3_e4", "S3_e5", "S3_e6", "S3_e7", "S3_e8", "S3_e9",
  "S3_e10", "S3_e11", "S3_e12"
), F_count_RK = c(
  2, 2, 7, 8, 4,
  2, 5, 7, 14, 5, 11, 10, 2, 2, 23, 12, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 23, 6, 16,
  10, 17, 13, 13, 10, 6, 13, 10, 13, 11
), Dating_flag = c(
  "No",
  "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
  "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
  "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
  "No", "No", "No", "No"
), Coaching_flag = c(
  "No", "No", "No",
  "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
  "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
  "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
  "Yes", "Yes"
), word = c(
  "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***",
  "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***",
  "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***",
  "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***",
  "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***", "F***"
)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: And the NA was indeed a bug that is now fixed in the latest development version of ggwordcloud!